# Elementary Casting (c#)

Tags: c#, casting

The following will compile but throw an exception:

```
public class a
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
}

public class b : a 
{

}

public class test()
{
   void Main()
   {
       b bar = (b)new a();
   }
}
```

Is the only option to construct a new instance of `b`, then manually copy each property/field from `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is not an instance of `b`. What your doing is essentially saying that an `Animal` is a `Dog` or that a `Tool` is a `Hammer` when in fact it is the other way around.

Comment: Ok, so var xyz = new b(){ foo = $instanceofa.foo}; ?

Comment: @maxp - Well ignoring the fact that `$` is an invalid identifier character yes but I would seriously reconsider using an object model where this is required. Essentially you are fighting the idioms of object oriented design when you do this. In fact you might as well write simple data structs to pass around to your procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'as':
b = new a() as b;
Just notice to check if b is null after using 'as'.
In your case you try to do upcasting since b inherite from a which isnt possiable in your case. 
if you try to achive polimorfisem you can do a = new b() as a;

Answer (score 1):

You can't upcast like this in C# and expect valid results.

If `b` adds new members, an `a` object will not suddenly have them, however you try to cast it.

Say `b` adds a `buzz()` method. Suppose that your cast actually works. What happens when you call `bar.buzz()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should have used it other way around (as ChaosPandion mentioned)

```
 a bar = new b();
```